# Why does c implementation of BST not include a data and key?

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I come from a java background so I'm a newbie when it comes to c. 
Please excuse me if my question is naive or something; my only goal is to learn.

I was looking at different implementation of structure of BST node; all of them only included data, just like this:

```
typedef struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node* left;
  struct node* right;
 } node;
```

To make things worst, data is used as a key.. I do realize that we can easily add to the struct a key AND data, but I was curious to why non of these sites included them both?

Comment: Why is it "worst"? If all you need is to look up integers, then this does the job perfectly well. Why add data that isn't needed?

Comment: Why not ask those sites? It's their code. We don't even know which sites you're talking about.

Comment: What key? BST is used to store data. If the data is used as key for something else - it's about that specific case.

Comment: Thank you all, I got it